# Tree implementation - C language

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a function to insert nodes in a binary tree, but I'm having the following error from the C compiler:
**parameter name omitted**.

A few words in my code are in Portugese so I will write their translation:

- esq is "left"
- dir is "right"
- valor is "value"

Can someone help me?

Here is the function:

```
void insere_Arvore(nodo* raiz, registro){
    if(raiz == NULL)
        {
        return 0
        }
    nodo* novo = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    if(novo == NULL)
        return 0;
    novo->dado->valor = valor1;
    novo->dir = NULL;
    novo->esq= NULL;
    if(*raiz = NULL)
    {
        *raiz = novo;
    }
    else{
        nodo* atual = *raiz;
        nodo* ant = NULL;
    }

    while(atual != NULL)
    {
        ant = atual;
        if (valor1 == atual->dado->valor){
            free(novo);
            return 0;
        }

        if(valor1 > atual->dado->valor)
        {
            atual = atual->dir;
        }
        else{
            atual = atual->esq;
        }
        if(valor1 > ant->dado->valor)
        {
            ant->dir = novo;
        }
        else{
            ant->esq = novo;
        }
        if(valor > ant->dado->valor){
            ant->dir = novo;
        }
        else{
            ant->esq = novo;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Here are all the structs I create:

```
typedef struct registro_st{         // sequência de objetos do mesmo tipo
    char login[50];
    char nome[50];
    float valor;
    struct registro *prox;
} registro;

typedef struct nodo_st{
    registro *dado;
    struct nodo_st *dir;
    struct nodo_st *esq;
} nodo;

typedef struct Lista_st{
    nodo *cabeca;
    nodo *cauda;
    int tamanho;
} lista;

nodo* raiz;

void insere_Arvore(nodo* raiz, registro){
    if(raiz == NULL)
        {
        return 0
        }
    nodo* novo = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    if(novo == NULL)
        return 0;
    novo->dado->valor = valor1;
    novo->dir = NULL;
    novo->esq= NULL;
        if(*raiz = NULL)
        {
            *raiz = novo;
        }
    else{
    nodo* atual = *raiz;
    nodo* ant = NULL;
    }

        while(atual != NULL)
            {
            ant = atual;
            if (valor1 == atual->dado->valor){
                            free(novo);
                            return 0;
            }

        if(valor1 > atual->dado->valor)
                                    {
                    atual = atual->dir;
        else{
                    atual = atual->esq;
        }
        if(valor1 > ant->dado->valor)
                                    {
        ant->dir = novo;
        }
        else{
        ant->esq = novo;
        }
        if(valor > ant->dado->valor){
            ant->dir = novo;
        }
        else{
        ant->esq = novo;
        }
        }
            }
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: `void insere_Arvore(nodo* raiz, registro)` - you forgot to name the second parameter, that is of type `registro`.

Comment: Note that the block `if(valor1 > atual->dado->valor)
                                    {
                    atual = atual->dir;
        else{
                    atual = atual->esq;
        }` won't compile because there's a `}` missing before the `else`.  Your code is erratically indented, which makes it hard.  I fixed that in the first extract, but the second still has the problem.

Comment: Also, in `typedef struct registro_st{
    char login[50];
    char nome[50];
    float valor;
    struct registro *prox;
} registro;`, you have three names — `struct registro_st`, `struct registro` (a different type — not defined — and `registro` (an alias for `struct registro_st` and not for `struct registro`).  Consistency is of paramount importance in programming.  You should probably use `struct registro`, as in `typedef struct registro {
    char login[50];
    char nome[50];
    float valor;
    struct registro *prox;
} registro;` to be self-consistent.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan Leffler. There are few problems in the syntax of the code. I'm working on that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Give a name to the second parameter like int, void, char, smth.. at function `void insere_Arvore(nodo* raiz, registro)`
- Then change your function type as int. Because you return 0 and 1 which are integer. `int insere_Arvore(nodo* raiz, [int, char, smth] registro)`

Comment: At that case, registro is a pointer to registro_st. Should I type struct registro_st?

Comment: Yep :) int insere_Arvore(nodo* raiz, struct registro_st registro) @Arduin

Comment: Works now. Thank you!!!

Comment: You are welcome :) @Arduin